# Google App Engine GQL Query - Date Query without year

Tags: python, google-app-engine, gql

I have a problem with making a GQL query to fetch dates without year. Basically, my data set consists of data of many years and I am trying to find the data for same date over many years.

How do I do that using GQL?

All help appreciated.

Comment: The problem as answered below is actually about you structure the data. GQL isn't really relevant.  Both ndb query interface and GQL will need the same changes to the model to support this type of query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to store month+day as a property, then query against that. With NDB, a ComputedProperty can make this easier:

```
class Model(ndb.Model):
  date_field = ndb.DateTimeProperty()
  month_day = ndb.ComputedProperty(lambda self: '%s-%s' % (self.date_field.month, self.date_field.day)
```